# Download file with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, file, download, android-asynctask

I am trying to download a file with asyncTask but is not working, there is no error messages or nothing, just dont download the file... i try everything but it appears that is not entering on the while... anybody know what can be the problem? I tested on my mobile, the url is ok too.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Starting download");
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            System.out.println("Downloading");
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file

            OutputStream output = new         FileOutputStream(root+"/downloadedfile.jpg");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }



    /**
     * After completing background task
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
       System.out.println("Downloaded");
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, why are you not returning any String from a method with String return type?

Comment: It appears that input stream read fails somehow. Check what url.openStream() returns.

Comment: How are you determining if the file is downloaded? Are you using **`adb shell ls`**? Are you using DDMS' file explorer? Are you testing this on a device and are examining external storage via a USB cable? Are you examining the contents of external storage via some on-device file manager app? Are you doing something else?

Comment: I am testing on a device and examining the external storage.

Comment: The url.openStream returns: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@31b6b86b).inputStream()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just ran your code, and it works fine for me.  The image was downloaded to the sdcard.

Just to note, make sure you have these permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here are the logs I got (note that I added a `ProgressDialog`):

```
03-21 16:53:46.422  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/Activity﹕ #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
03-21 16:53:56.211  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/Activity﹕ #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
03-21 16:54:06.441  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload I/System.out﹕ Starting download
03-21 16:54:06.441  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/Dialog﹕ checkMirrorLinkEnabled returns : false
03-21 16:54:06.441  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/Dialog﹕ showing allowed
03-21 16:54:06.461  21017-25126/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload I/System.out﹕ Downloading
03-21 16:54:06.461  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/Activity﹕ #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
03-21 16:54:06.481  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
03-21 16:54:06.481  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
03-21 16:54:06.491  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
03-21 16:54:06.491  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
03-21 16:54:11.596  21017-21017/com.imagedownload.danielnugent.imagedownload I/System.out﹕ Downloaded
```

Just in case this will be useful, here is the full MainActivity.java code that worked for me.  (url is a placeholder):

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute("http://www.example.com/IMG.jpg");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            System.out.println("Starting download");

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                System.out.println("Downloading");
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root+"/downloadedfile.jpg");
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }



        /**
         * After completing background task
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            System.out.println("Downloaded");

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But then you should return fileurl or filepath from doInBackground in case of success and check file_url for null in onPostExecute before you shout 'Downloaded'.

Comment: This sample works but needs to add permissions request to write to external folder, see here for working code to request permissions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385895/proper-way-of-requesting-write-external-storage-permission