# Get content from html page in Android

Tags: android

I want to get content of one page to String.  I tried some ways to do it.

My code I tried to use:

```
    class GetWebContent extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... url) {

        URL mypage = new URL(url[0]);  //HERE IS ERROR MalformedURLException
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            mypage.openStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(inputLine);


            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        return sb.toString();

}
```

I edited code, so now I'm getting error `java.net.MalformedURLException`
Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: You said what's wrong. "Network on main thread exception". Google for it, and you'll know what to do.

Comment: @CommonWare , I follow the link you gave me, but I get error `java.net.MalformedURLException` when I try to declare URL. How to solve it? I edited my code.

@Christine , I googled for it and google said It was wrong because I need to use AsyncTask. So I did, but still another error, and google has different answers...

Comment: The given code cannot be correct because there is no constructor for `URL` that takes a single `URL`. If URL is actually `String` then `url[0]` being null would cause that exception. (Or providing a faulty URL)

Comment: @Kiskae there is constructor for `URL` that takes one parameter. I changed AsyncTask to `AsyncTask<String,Void,String>` . Can you tell me how to change this code that It could work? Thank you.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188557/download-file-with-asynctask for an example of downloading, the only thing you need to change it to store the output as a string, like your current solution does.

Comment: Thank you for research. My code just started working. I'm fighting with Jsoup now to remove html tags from downloaded content. Thank you for help.

Comment: If you change your question, deleting lines, then the comments don't make sense any more. Please don't remove essential info from your question.