# Proper Way of Requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have struggled trying to figure out how the storage system work on Android. Now I am stuck at requesting permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and I am using Android 7.1.1. Here is my code:

```
int check = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1024);
        }
```

UPDATE: So the code does work, it didn't work before because I had a typo in AndroidManifest.xml, thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Have you mentioned permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest file ?

Comment: I absoltely have, I wrote something like "<user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />"

Comment: This works well http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143769/%D9%90android-class-to-handle-marshmallowpermission

Comment: permission should be <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @sapanravani Isn't your code the same as mine?

Comment: @x1uan you have written user-permission in place of uses-permission

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission/43322136#43322136

Comment: @sapan You are absolutely right! OMG, thank you so much! I almost killed myselft.

Comment: @x1uan most welcome...:)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Add permission to your manifest file

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I did, <user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Problem solved, apparently, I should use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: The other answer is correct, you have to add run time permission Too.

Comment: Marshmallow onwards you need to add runtime permission. This cannot be the accepted answer!

Comment: we require run time permission too

Comment: where is runtime permission @FaisalShaikh ?

Comment: @gumuruh https://stackoverflow.com/a/43385945/4291272

Answer (score 28):

Try this,

```
private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        //do here
    }
} else {
     //do here
}
```

get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write in your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you wan't to check multiple permissions at time then add permission into PERMISSIONS array like:

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
```

Comment: After read your code, I think the main difference is the requestPermissions() part, so I tried something like "ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1024); Not luck.

Comment: WHERE did you find the number 122?? I cannot find a list of android requestCodes.

Comment: Sorry 112.  Still, I have searched and searched and there is no resource to show requestCodes anywhere :(

Comment: You can use the number you want.

Comment: if WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE require user to click (as an approval). What about INTERNET permission? Does it also need to be requested too....? @Komal12